# regex mysql query for specfic string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

hello i am trying to search `ddw_0_op1` with mysql regex serach query

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key RLIKE '(?=.*ddw_)(?=.*_op1)'
```

but in results its also displaying results from this field

```
_ddw_0_op1
```

but i want to display results only from this field `ddw_0_op1` . how i can achieve that
[image]
in this picture i want results from http links field
i hope that makes sense now

Comment: Well, `.*ddw_` matches `_ddw_`. Not exactly sure what you're looking for...

Comment: You need to give better examples of things you _do_ want to match and things that you _don't_.  Do you literally only want to match "ddw_0_op1"?

Comment: Since when does mysql regex support lookarounds?

Comment: the 0 increases with numbers @ patrick

Comment: So again, you need to provide sample values and indicate which should match and which should not.

Comment: @Patrick q edited my question can you check please

Comment: Why do you need regex? Try `WHERE meta_key LIKE 'ddw_%_op1'` or if you need to narrow the wildcard down to digits with regex `WHERE meta_key RLIKE '^ddw_[[:digit:]]+_op1$'`

Comment: i dont know i think regex seems faster well anyways thanks it worked

Comment: you're welcome. `LIKE` is the way to go, if you don't need the power of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `INDEX(meta_key)`, this may be faster:

```
WHERE meta_key LIKE   'ddw_%_op1'
  AND meta_key RLIKE '^ddw_[[:digit:]]+_op1$'
```

First the `LIKE` (without a leading wildcard) can use the index.  Then the `RLIKE` will verify that only digits are in the middle (without using the index).

Since this smells like a WP schema, here are some more [*tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) on `wp_postmeta`.  (The tips won't speed up your ddw query, but may help others.)